# Обработка цикла в PHP

Tags: php

Никак не могу разобраться как сделать i-ую переменную в цикле.

```
for ( $i=1; $i<=3; $i++ ) {
         $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `GGS_eq` WHERE `index` = '$_POST[search_index]' AND btn_no = '$i'") );
        // если в таблице находим данный Индекс с нужной i-ой кнопкой, то:
        if ( $Row ) { $caller_title_btn_.$i = 'Кнопка: '.$Row['name']; }
        // если не находим, то:
        else { }
     }
```

Мне нужно присвоить `$caller_title_btn_` (от 1 до 3). Ни как не могу понять, как склеить временную с `$i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом

```
${'caller_title_btn_' . $i}
```

Но лучше использовать

```
$caller_title_btn[$i]
```

Comment: Да, спасибо!! Это то что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Есть ответ на вопрос, но то что вы делаете называют кастылём так как есть другие механизмы например массив

```
$caller_title_btn[$i]
```

подумайте о геморое который вас ждёт, вам же придёться эти переменные где то ещё применять расширять присваивать и т.д.

Comment: да, конечно, я в самом вопросе написал о том, что - скорее всего, я что-то делаю не так... и есть другие способы. Но в моем конкретном случае этот вариант вполне подходит. Спасибо!

Comment: Вариант выше или мой @VasilyUK

Comment: Я использовал вариант `${'caller_title_btn_' . $i}`, но потом переделал на  `$caller_title_btn[$i]`. Не знаю, кто из Вас первым предложил второй вариант и кто именно помог. Если вопрос в этом...

Comment: @VasilyUK ну я ответил в 12 часов 4 октября а он добил в 20 часов 4 октября. Я первый

Comment: ну не знаю что сказать... мне его первый вариант тоже помог, хотя твой "красивее" и проще, ну и как я понял, правильней.

Comment: я так понимаю, ты хочешь, чтобы я отметил твой ответ как решение моего вопроса!?

Comment: @VasilyUK Как хочешь мне как то без разницы рейтинги всякие, главное что бы ответ помагал.